# Custom Dialog in Nested Recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I have implemented a expandable nested RecyclerView . Now I want to display an AlertDialog when an item of RecyclerView is clicked. I tried many ways and none of them worked. Here is my adapter class,

Answer (score 0):

```
**Parent Adopter class code**'
$ package com.pscripto.mxmoviehub;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint; import android.app.Dialog; import android.content.Context; import android.util.Log; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.LinearLayout; import android.widget.TextView; import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull; import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper; import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager; import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

public class ParentAdopter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ParentAdopter.ParentAdopterViewHolder> {    private List<Movie_Model> movieModelList;   private   List<Child_Model> child_modelList;   private   ChildAdopter childAdopter;   private   Context context;
    public ParentAdopter(@NonNull List<Movie_Model> movieModelList) {
        this.movieModelList = movieModelList;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ParentAdopterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rootview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vertical_rv,parent,false);

        return new ParentAdopterViewHolder(rootview);
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ParentAdopterViewHolder holder, int position) { Movie_Model movie_model = movieModelList.get(position); holder.tvSection.setText(movie_model.getHeaderTitle()); if (movie_model.getHeaderTitle().contains("Latest Movies")){ childAdopter= new ChildAdopter(getLatestMovie(),context);


    } else  if (movie_model.getHeaderTitle().contains("Action Movies")){
    childAdopter= new ChildAdopter(getActionMovies(),context);

} else if (movie_model.getHeaderTitle().contains("Romantic Movies")){
    childAdopter = new ChildAdopter(getRomanticMovies(),context); }  holder.childRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true); holder.childRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL,false)); holder.childRecyclerview.setAdapter(childAdopter); //customClicl();

    } private void customClicl(){
        childAdopter.setCustomClickListener(new ChildAdopter.CustomClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }); }


    private List<Child_Model> getLatestMovie(){ child_modelList = new ArrayList<>(); child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.salmankhanmovieone,"Bajrangi Bhaijaan"));

        child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.pati,"Pati Patni Aur Woh"));
        child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.blackmail,"Blackmail 2019"));
        child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.bharat,"Bharat 2019"));
        child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.gang,"Gangster 3"));


        return child_modelList;
    }
    private List<Child_Model> getActionMovies(){
        child_modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.salmankhanmovieone,"Bajrangi Bhaijaan"));
        child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.blackmail,"Blackmail 2019"));
        child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.bharat,"Bharat 2019"));
        child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.gang,"Gangster 3"));



        return child_modelList;
    }
    private List<Child_Model> getRomanticMovies(){
        child_modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.star,"Love Star"));
        child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.bestofme,"The Best Of Me"));
        child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.trailer,"After Trailer"));
        child_modelList.add(new Child_Model(R.drawable.buylove,"Cant Buy Love"));


        return child_modelList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movieModelList.size();
    }

    class ParentAdopterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { TextView tvSection; RecyclerView childRecyclerview;
        public ParentAdopterViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvSection = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvsection);
            childRecyclerview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_rv);

        }
    }


}'$'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Child adopter class**

package com.pscripto.mxmoviehub;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class ChildAdopter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildAdopter.ChildAdopterViewHolder> {
 private    List<Child_Model> child_modelList;
   private ChildAdopter childAdopter ;

  private   Context context;
   private CustomClickListener customClickListener;

    public void setCustomClickListener(CustomClickListener customClickListener) {
        this.customClickListener = customClickListener;
    }

    interface CustomClickListener{
    void onItemClick (int position);
}

    public ChildAdopter(List<Child_Model> child_modelList, Context context) {
        this.child_modelList = child_modelList;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChildAdopterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View rootview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizental_layout, parent, false);
        return new ChildAdopterViewHolder(rootview);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChildAdopterViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Child_Model child_model = child_modelList.get(position);
        holder.movieImg.setImageResource(child_model.getImgResId());
        holder.movieTitle.setText(child_model.getTitle());
        Boolean isExpanded = child_modelList.get(position).getExpanded();
        holder.expandidLayout.setVisibility(isExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return child_modelList.size();
    }

    class ChildAdopterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView movieImg ,ivEdit,ivDel;
        private TextView movieTitle;
        LinearLayout expandidLayout;


        public ChildAdopterViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            movieImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_img);
            movieTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_name);
            expandidLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandable_layout);
            ivEdit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_Edit);
            ivDel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.del_img);

            movieTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    Child_Model child_model = child_modelList.get(position);
                    child_model.setExpanded(!child_model.getExpanded());
                    notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
                    }

            });
            ivEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position= getAdapterPosition();
                    if (customClickListener != null){
                        customClickListener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```